# How can solve Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, heroku

I have setup a small web application on heroku.com in Django which returns **JsonResponse** you can see it [here.](https://justgiveme.herokuapp.com/)

```
 {
 name: "shubham",
 college: "MAIT",
 subject: "java"
 }
```

And I also setup server locally on my computer which accepts that JSON and it appends with HTML element here my javascript file :

```
    $(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'https://justgiveme.herokuapp.com/',
            dataType :"Json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Success !");
            },
            error : function()
            {
                alert("failed !");
            }
        });
    });
```

but when I open localhost it gives me **alert("failed !")** instead of **alert("success !");** .
I have check on Chrome console and I found this error :

[image]

Any helpful suggestion is appreciable .

Comment: remove the `dataType :"Json",` and contentType params from the request and try again. if it doesn't work still, you need to adjust the server's response headers.

Comment: @dandavis again failed :(

Comment: then you aren't shipping something "plainly", and therefore must use CORS headers; see @Lucas's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (CORS) on your heroku app. Right now its failing because the request isn't coming from the domain which the first resource was retrieved from. In your case, 127.0.0.1.

Here's a starting point for Django on CORS: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is because the browser sends a preflight request to check if a cross origin request is allowed. You can see it being sent when viewing the Network tab in the Chrome Inspector. It will be an OPTIONS request to the url that is specified in the ajax.

In order to resolve this issue, the server needs to let the browser know that cross origin requests are allowed. To do this, Django must respond to the preflight request with the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header specified. The header's value must be either be the website you are requesting from or "*" to allow any website.

```
//Any website
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
//Specific website
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a
>   resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource
>   itself serves. For example, an HTML page served from
>   http://domain-a.com makes an  src request for
>   http://domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web today load
>   resources like CSS stylesheets, images and scripts from separate
>   domains.
>
> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts.  For example, XMLHttpRequest follows
>   the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest
>   could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web
>   applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow XMLHttpRequest
>   to make cross-domain requests

you can read more about CORS [here .](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Detailed explanation of **how to setup CORS in Django ?**

This is because of no provision in the REST API to handle Cross-Origin-Resource-Request (CORS). To enable it in the REST API, we need django-cors-headers as recommended in Django REST Framework documentation. The minimal settings required are as follows.

**Step 0** - install django-cors-headers .

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

**Step 1** - In settings.py, add the following entry in INSTALLED_APPS tuple.

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
 '......',
 'corsheaders',
 '......'
)
```

**Step 2** - In settings.py, add the following entries at the top of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple.

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 )
```

**Step 3** - Add the following flag variable in settings.py

```
 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

you can read more about CORS in django [here .](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

We are done !!